# Guest Checkout Strange behavior

Tags: checkout

I’m having a strange problem with Guest Checkout in magento 2.0.2 version. I have done **Allow Guest Checkout  Yes** and **Enable Onepage Checkout Yes**.
also **Enable Persistence No** and **Disable Guest Checkout if Cart Contains Downloadable Items No**.

But Guest checkout works only (after Flush Cache and clear History) if I go through Mini cart -- Go to Checkout link one time only. When I go through cart page,shipping Fields are invisible.